# Linear Algebra Matrices Help

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Find the values of c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, and c<sub>3</sub> so that $$c_1(-10, 20, -3) + c_2(-5, 4, 0) + c_3(5, 0, 0) = (-15, 4, 9)$$

My Answer:

c<sub>1</sub> = $-3$,
c<sub>2</sub> = $14$,
c<sub>3</sub> = $5$

I re-did the question a few times but I do not know where I went wrong.

Comment: You solved $-60 + 4c_2 = 4$ incorrectly.

Comment: there is no -60+4c2=4?

Comment: Since $c_1=-3$, the equation $$20c_1+4c_2=4$$ becomes $$-60+4c_2=4$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just made a mistake in your calculation, it should be
$$c_1 = -3, c_2 = 16, c_3 = 9$$

by solving it
$$-10c_1-5c_2+5c_3=-15$$
$$20c_1+4c_2=4$$
$$-3c_1=9$$
then,

$$c_1 = -3$$
$$4c_2 = 64 $$
$$c_2 = 16$$
$$5c_3 = -15-30+90$$
$$c_3 = 9$$

Comment: $16\cdot 5 = 80$, so $c_3 = \frac{-15-30+80}{5} = 7$.